# Trouble with calculating random occurrence

Tags: python

Let's say I have this code

```
import random

def fooFunc():
    return 1
```

What is the overall chance of `fooFunc` being executed when using the code below?

```
if random.randrange(4096)==1:
    fooFunc()
if random.randrange(256)==1:
    fooFunc()
```

Comment: you do realize why it's called random.. and make question look like one you can't say it trouble

Comment: i just want to know how to calculate the overall chance of fooFunc happening.. if i had only random.randrange(4096)==1 then it would be obvious that the chance would be 1/4096 but now that i have 2 randrange what's the overall chance of fooFunc happening?

Comment: try `[random.randrange(256) for x in range(300)].count(1)` which return number of 1 exist in list of 300 random numbers; where you may get 0 sometimes or 2 or more or less. you can't gurantee the result

Comment: the code that i posted is just an example.. it's just that i just saw a similar one somewhere in a game and i just want to calculate the chance of fooFunc happening for RNG purposes..

Comment: @TetsuyaGR I'm not sure of the probabilities of the random library. You may want to ask about it in the Python room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `random.randrange` can be treated as independent random selection, *provided* you don't know the seed and are happy to treat the output of a PRNG as a random variable.

> What's the overall chance of fooFunc being executed?

Assuming you don't care about tracking whether `fooFunc` is called twice?
This is just the normal probability calculation, similar to "what is the chance of rolling at least one 6 when I roll two dice". To do this, it is easier to re-formulate the question as "What is the probability that I don't roll any 6", and subtract that from 1.0, because there is only one combination of failing both checks, whilst there are 3 combinations of succeeding one or other or both.

So `p = 1 - ((4095/4096) * (255/256))`

Comment: great answer @neil-slater

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest this isn't a python problem and better suited to https://math.stackexchange.com/ - to ask about probabilities.

As random.randrange(x) produces a number between 0 and x (including 0, but NOT including x), you have a `1/x probability` of any specific number being produced.

Please see Neil Slater's answer for calculating the specific probability in your situation.

*(Please see here if you want to look at the internals of random.randrange(): [How does a randrange() function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633241/how-does-a-randrange-function-work))*